# Navigation [destination_name] is unknown to this NavController

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation, uinavigationcontroller

I have seen this question several times but mostly from people needing to go back from C to A but mine goes the other way.

Here is what my navgraph looks like (portion of it)

HOME -> NestedGraph Account - >Nested Graph Contacts inside this nested graph account.

What i want to do is go from HOME to Contacts.
I've tried global actions from every fragment in the xml navgraph and each time I got the same error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.example.techcrea:id/contactsList referenced from action com.example.techcrea:id/action_global_contactsList4 is unknown to this NavController
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:789)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:730)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:716)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:704)
    **at com.example.techcrea.Fragments.Home.Home.onClick(Home.java:126)**
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6329)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25002)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:809)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
```

But when I access "contacts" with "navigate" from the Account "simple" action , it works properly. It's only the "shortcut" from Home that does not work.

Here is my Navgraph, I put the global action in top of it but I tried to put it at every place of this xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navgraph_bottomview"
    app:startDestination="@id/mnuHome">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_contactsList4"
        app:destination="@id/contactsList"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@id/mnuHome"
        android:name="com.example.techcrea.Fragments.Home.Home"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mnuHome_to_accountMain"
            app:destination="@id/mnuAccount" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mnuHome_to_mnuBills"
            app:destination="@id/mnuBills" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mnuHome_to_mnuContracts"
            app:destination="@id/mnuContracts" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mnuHome_to_mnuHelp"
            app:destination="@id/mnuHelp" />

    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@id/mnuBills"
        android:name="com.example.techcrea.Fragments.Bills.BillsMain"
        android:label="fragment_bills_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_bills_main" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@id/mnuContracts"
        android:name="com.example.techcrea.Fragments.Contracts.ContractsMain"
        android:label="fragment_contracts_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_contracts_main" />
    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/mnuHelp"
        app:startDestination="@id/mnuHelp" >
        <fragment
            android:id="@id/mnuHelp"
            android:name="com.example.techcrea.Fragments.Help.Help"
            android:label="fragment_help"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_help">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_mnuHelp_to_helpStep2"
                app:destination="@id/helpStep2" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/helpStep2"
            android:name="com.example.techcrea.Fragments.Help.HelpStep2"
            android:label="fragment_help_step2"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_help_step2">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_helpStep2_to_helpStep3A"
                app:destination="@id/helpStep3A" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_helpStep2_to_helpStep3B"
                app:destination="@id/helpStep3B" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/helpStep3B"
            android:name="com.example.techcrea.Fragments.Help.HelpStep3B"
            android:label="fragment_help_step3_b"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_help_step3_b" />
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/helpStep3A"
            android:name="com.example.techcrea.Fragments.Help.HelpStep3A"
            android:label="fragment_help_step3"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_help_step3" />
    </navigation>
    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/mnuAccount"
        app:startDestination="@id/mnuAccount" >
        <fragment
            android:id="@id/mnuAccount"
            android:name="com.example.techcrea.Fragments.Account.AccountMain"
            android:label="fragment_account_main"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_account_main">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_mnuAccount_to_accountAboutUs"
                app:destination="@id/accountAboutUs" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_mnuAccount_to_accountChangePassword"
                app:destination="@id/accountChangePassword" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_mnuAccount_to_accountEditInformations"
                app:destination="@id/accountEditInformations" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_mnuAccount_to_contactsList"
                app:destination="@id/contacts" />
        </fragment>
        <navigation
            android:id="@+id/contacts"
            app:startDestination="@id/contactsList">
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/contactDisplayOne"
                android:name="com.example.techcrea.Fragments.Account.ContactDisplayOne"
                android:label="fragment_contact_display_one"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_contact_display_one">
                <action
                    android:id="@+id/action_contactDisplayOne_to_contactEditOne"
                    app:destination="@id/contactEditOne" />
            </fragment>
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/contactAddOne"
                android:name="com.example.techcrea.Fragments.Account.ContactAddOne"
                android:label="fragment_contact_add_one"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_contact_add_one" >
                <action
                    android:id="@+id/action_contactAddOne_to_contactsList"
                    app:destination="@id/contactsList"
                    app:popUpTo="@+id/contactAddOne" />
            </fragment>
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/contactsList"
                android:name="com.example.techcrea.Fragments.Account.ContactsList"
                android:label="fragment_account_watchcontacts"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_account_watchcontacts">
                <action
                    android:id="@+id/action_contactsList_to_contactAddOne"
                    app:destination="@id/contactAddOne"
                    app:popUpTo="@+id/contacts" />
                <action
                    android:id="@+id/action_contactsList_to_contactEditOne"
                    app:destination="@id/contactEditOne" />
                <action
                    android:id="@+id/action_contactsList_to_contactDisplayOne"
                    app:destination="@id/contactDisplayOne" />
            </fragment>
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/contactEditOne"
                android:name="com.example.techcrea.Fragments.Account.ContactEditOne"
                android:label="fragment_contact_edit_one"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_contact_edit_one">
                <action
                    android:id="@+id/action_contactEditOne_to_contactsList"
                    app:destination="@id/contactsList" />
            </fragment>

        </navigation>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/accountAboutUs"
            android:name="com.example.techcrea.Fragments.Account.AccountAboutUs"
            android:label="fragment_account_about_us"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_account_about_us" />
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/accountChangePassword"
            android:name="com.example.techcrea.Fragments.Account.AccountChangePassword"
            android:label="fragment_account_change_password"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_account_change_password" />
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/accountEditInformations"
            android:name="com.example.techcrea.Fragments.Account.AccountEditInformations"
            android:label="fragment_account_edit_informations"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_account_edit_informations" >
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_accountEditInformations_to_mnuAccount"
                app:destination="@id/mnuAccount" />
        </fragment>

    </navigation>

</navigation>
```

Here is the place where I call it, every other link is working fine (direct links).
The bottom navigation view is working fine too even if Account is in a nested graph.

```
package com.example.techcrea.Fragments.Home;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;

import com.example.techcrea.Model.User;
import com.example.techcrea.R;
import com.example.techcrea.Services.DataStorage;
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Home extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    //VIEW ATTRIBUTES ##############################################################################
    /**
     * The text that displays our username
     */
    private TextView displayUserName;
    /**
     * The horizontal dividers
     */
    private View divider1, divider2, divider3, divider4, divider5;

    /**
     * The small icons left of each row
     */
    private ImageView iconBills, iconAccount, iconContracts,iconContacts;

    /**
     * The pics for each type of contract
     */
    private ImageView imgFiber, imgPhone, imgOther;

    /**
     * Clickable lines
     */
    private LinearLayout accountRow, billRow, contractsRow, contactsRow, helpBlock;

   //DATA ATTRIBUTES ##############################################################################
    private User user;


    /**
     * Fragment sole constructor
     */
    public Home() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     //Here we set the text that displays the user name
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

     user = DataStorage.getInstance().getUser().getValue();
     loadViewComponents(view);
     displayUserName.setText(user.getUserName());
     return view;

    }


    /**
     * Binds the design components to variables
     */
    public void loadViewComponents(View view){
        displayUserName = view.findViewById(R.id.txtWelcomeUser);
        divider1 = view.findViewById(R.id.dvd1);
        divider2 = view.findViewById(R.id.dvd2);
        divider3 = view.findViewById(R.id.dvd3);
        divider4 = view.findViewById(R.id.dvd4);
        divider5 = view.findViewById(R.id.dvd5);
        iconBills = view.findViewById(R.id.iconBills);
        iconAccount = view.findViewById(R.id.iconAccount);
        iconContracts = view.findViewById(R.id.iconContracts);
        iconContacts = view.findViewById(R.id.iconContacts);
        imgFiber = view.findViewById(R.id.img_fiber);
        imgPhone = view.findViewById(R.id.img_phone);
        imgOther = view.findViewById(R.id.img_other);
        accountRow = view.findViewById(R.id.row_account);
        billRow = view.findViewById(R.id.row_bills);
        contractsRow = view.findViewById(R.id.row_contracts);
        contactsRow = view.findViewById(R.id.row_contact);
        helpBlock = view.findViewById(R.id.row_help);
        setListeners();
     }


    /**
     * The onClick Listeners for the menu rows.
     */
     public void setListeners(){
        accountRow.setOnClickListener(this);
        billRow.setOnClickListener(this);
        helpBlock.setOnClickListener(this);
        contactsRow.setOnClickListener(this);
        contractsRow.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * this method
     * @param v the source of the click
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.equals(accountRow)) {
            Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(R.id.action_mnuHome_to_accountMain);
        } else if (v.equals(billRow)) {
            Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(R.id.action_mnuHome_to_mnuBills);
        } else if (v.equals(helpBlock)) {
            Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(R.id.action_mnuHome_to_mnuHelp);
        } else if (v.equals(contactsRow)) {
            **Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(R.id.action_global_contactsList4);**
        } else if (v.equals(contractsRow)) {
            Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(R.id.action_mnuHome_to_mnuContracts);
        }

    }}
```

And this is my main activity setting up the navcontrollers:

```
/**
 * This is the "home" activity and it contains all the fragments we will navigate in.
 * This activity is called by the LoginActivity.
 * @author Caroline
 */
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private BottomNavigationView bView;

    /**
     * Navigation controller
     */
    private NavController navController;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Android default code, do not touch _______________________________________________________
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        //__________________________________________________________________________________________

        //Toolbar instanciation
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolbar_color));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);

        //Bottom Navigation : selected item by default at activity launch
        bView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation); //Bottom botnavigation bar
        bView.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED); //This line is to 
        force the display of texts under nav icons. Otherwise, only the active icon has its label 
        visible.


        //Making it reactive to in-fragment links
        //We add the fragment container layout to our botnavigation controller so it observes 
        botnavigation.
        // To change the way the navController interacts with layout, please see 
    Res>Navigation>navgraph_bottomview.xml
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.fragmentContainer);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bView, navController);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController);
        }


}
```

Please excuse my odd english and my code mistakes I'm french, still a student, currently in internship.

Comment: Did you find the solution?  I am getting the same error.

Comment: Nope, I did not, so I removed the access to the contact list from A, now I Can only access it from B. No more issue, but no solution either :'(

Answer (score 0):

You need to `include` the C graph in your A navgraph.  I.e. create a separate nav graph and include it like this:

`<include app:graph="@navigation/mnuHelp_graph" />`

Comment: I twill try that When I come home from holiday but then the C graph will not be linked to/pop back to/ the B graph again When called from A, will it ?